# preventDefault not working in IE

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form with ajax, the form itself is loaded via a ajax event

The following Jquery code works in FF?chrome. In IE, the form submission is not prevented

```
$("#admin_main").delegate("#create_user_form", "submit", function (event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
    $.post('create_user', $("#create_user_form").serialize(), function (data) {
        $("#admin_main").html(data);
    }, "html");
});
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: I am afraid you can have serious problems with this... Once I needed to prevent the default behaviour of the onkeyup event. And it didn't work in IE. I have never found any solution (that was in pure JavaScript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery normalizes this, you can reliably call [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), like this:

```
$("#admin_main").delegate("#create_user_form", "submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post('create_user', $("#create_user_form").serialize(), function (data) {
    $("#admin_main").html(data);
  }, "html");
});
```

Or if you want to completely kill the event, `return false`:

```
$("#admin_main").delegate("#create_user_form", "submit", function () {
  $.post('create_user', $("#create_user_form").serialize(), function (data) {
    $("#admin_main").html(data);
  }, "html");
  return false;
});
```

The reason it's not an issue to call it is because it's not a browser-specific event object that you're dealing with, it's a [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) that has normalized behavior.

Comment: Hi I already tried that, doesn't work. Above code is supposed to work

Comment: @RisingSun - You have another issue then, it's not the above code...for example invalid markup, or any JS error before this will bomb out and normal browser behavior takes over....are you not seeing an error in the status bar?

Comment: Well, even return false; doesn't prevent form submission.

Comment: Well. the console shows both events occuring in rapid succession

Comment: @RisingSun - And you're getting no errors at all?  Which version of IE?

Comment: You got it! IE9 was doing some compatiblity mischief. Will immediately uninstall it. Thnx

Comment: @RisingSun - Ah, that makes more sense :) If it helps, IE9 has *many* JavaScript/event issues still, it needs a bit of work :)